# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 - suddenly cannot connect to specific WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

All of the sudden my wifi in my home is not working with my laptop (Dell XPS 15 9550). The laptop can connect to other wifi's such as my friends', University or my phone's. It even so happens, that once in a while (usually in the evening) my home wifi does work with my laptop. But most of the time it is just connected as if all was normal, but it really has no connection to the Internet. My wifi does work, since I have other devices connected to it as well at all times.

I don't know if this helps, but when I connect to another wifi, where I get Internet, this message shows: “Network service discovery disabled. Your current network has a .local domain, which is not recommended and incompatible with the Avahi network service discovery. The service has been disabled.”

Hopefully someone can give me a helping hand - thanks in advance!